# Custom Meta Tags in Next.js 14 for Social Media Previews Slow Down Page Rendering

Tags: next.js

I'm working with **Next.js 14** and looking to customize meta tags dynamically for enhanced website previews on social platforms like Discord and Twitter. The metadata I need to display requires backend calls, which I've implemented using `generateMetadata()` as per the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata).

However, I've encountered a performance issue: incorporating `generateMetadata()` slows down my page rendering significantly. Prior to this, the initial HTML would load almost instantaneously, with API data fetching occurring post-load.

Previously, I used a workaround where I'd extract the user agent from the request object to determine if the requester was Discord or Twitter. If so, I'd call my API backend to generate the necessary metadata; if not, I'd bypass this step to avoid unnecessary load time, as it's redundant for regular browser display. With the introduction of `generateMetadata()`, I no longer have access to the request object or any means to identify the user agent.

I'm looking for suggestions or best practices on how to approach this. Is there a way to access the user agent or an alternative method to conditionally generate meta tags without compromising page load speed?

Answer (score 0):

In a development environment this is to be expected. I use code similar to the below example (oversimplified) in production and have not seen performance issues whatsoever:

```
interface Props {
  params: { id: string };
}

export default async function MyPage(props: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  return <>{props.params.id}</>
}

export async function generateMetadata(props: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  return await getUserMetadata(props.params.id);
}
```

Anyway, if this also happens in production, it is either an error on your site or a bug in Next.js that would best be posted as issue in the repository.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. It is slow but as expected to be slow (100ms which is the timing for the server to respond), I am looking to optimize this by skipping the request when it is not necessary.